# How do I relax the non-exhaustive patterns check for a nested match on known variants?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

How do I persuade the Rust compiler that the internal `match` expression is fine here, as the outer `match` has already restricted the possible types?

```rust
enum Op {
    LoadX,
    LoadY,
    Add,
}

fn test(o: Op) {
    match o {
        Op::LoadX | Op::LoadY => {
            // do something common with them for code reuse:
            print!("Loading ");

            // do something specific to each case:
            match o {
                // now I know that `o` can only be LoadX | LoadY,
                // but how to persuade the compiler?
                Op::LoadX => print!("x"), /* LoadX specific */
                Op::LoadY => print!("y"), /* LoadY specific */
                _ => panic!("shouldn't happen!"),
            }

            println!("...");
        }

        Op::Add => println!("Adding"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    test(Op::LoadX);
    test(Op::LoadY);
    test(Op::Add);
}
```

I tried two approaches, but neither seems to work.

1. Name the or-pattern and then match using that name:

   ```
   match o {
       load@(Op::LoadX | Op::LoadY) => {
       // ...
       match load {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

   That's not valid Rust syntax.
2. Name and bind every constructor:

   ```rust
   match o {
       load@Op::LoadX | load@Op::LoadY => {
       // ...
       match load {
          //...
       }
   }
   ```

   That still doesn't satisfy the exhaustiveness check, hence the same error message:

   ```
   error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `Add` not covered
     --> src/main.rs:14:19
      |
   14 |             match load {
      |                   ^ pattern `Add` not covered
   ```

Is there any idiomatic way of solving this problem or should I just put `panic!("shouldn't happen")` all over the place or restructure the code?

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f3689bec2afc25ee121b64de05a3c3c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Conceptually, nothing prevents you from doing `o = Op::Add` between the outer match and the inner match. It's totally possible for the variant to change between the two matches.

I'd probably follow [Stargateur's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049375/155423), but if you didn't want to restructure your enum, remember that there are multiple techniques of abstraction in Rust. For example, *functions* are pretty good for reusing code, and *closures* (or traits) are good for customization of logic.

```
enum Op {
    LoadX,
    LoadY,
    Add,
}

fn load<R>(f: impl FnOnce() -> R) {
    print!("Loading ");
    f();
    println!("...");
}

fn test(o: Op) {
    match o {
        Op::LoadX => load(|| print!("x")),
        Op::LoadY => load(|| print!("y")),
        Op::Add => println!("Adding"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    test(Op::LoadX);
    test(Op::LoadY);
    test(Op::Add);
}
```

> should I just put `panic!("shouldn't happen")`

You should use [`unreachable!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) instead of `panic!` as it's more semantically correct to the programmer.

Comment: > Conceptually, nothing prevents you from doing o = Op::Add between the outer match and the inner match.

`o` is immutable.

Comment: as @MikeMueller stated, i also wonder if in the case of immutable variables conceptionally it should be possible, right? or is there another reason why this cannot work?

Comment: It is valid to rebind the variable (i.e. do a let o = ... inbetween)
playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=276db744acf8106060456b8438ad8916

Answer (score 3):

I think that you just need to refactor your code, obviously `LoadX` and `LoadY` are very close. So I think you should create a second enumeration that regroup them:

```rust
enum Op {
    Load(State),
    Add,
}

enum State {
    X,
    Y,
}

fn test(o: Op) {
    match o {
        Op::Load(state) => {
            // do something common with them for code reuse
            print!("Loading ");

            // do something specific to each case:
            match state {
                State::X => print!("x"),
                State::Y => print!("y"),
            }

            println!("...");
        }

        Op::Add => println!("Adding"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    test(Op::Load(State::X));
    test(Op::Load(State::Y));
    test(Op::Add);
}
```

This make more sense to me. I think this is a better way to express what you want.

Comment: Yes, restructuring the code will help of course. But I was more interested in hinting the compiler in the original case. However, probably most of the real world cases can be handled in a way you propose.

Comment: In my situation I have lots of 3-letters assembly mnemonics for opcodes like: LDX, LDY, LDA, STX, STA, etc. It would be nice to keep them as is: just flat enum values, so that they can match original mnemonics. Otherwise, it would be something like LD(X), which is not as readable.

Comment: @dying_sphynx so you want a flat enum but still be able to regroup them, you can't have both I think, it's opposite. Maybe there is a crate that flat nested enum. But still I don't advice it, I found `Load(Register::X)` way more readable that LDX. Remember, you are doing Rust, not assembly. Express your virtual machine in Rust, don't just copy assembly. Anyway, my solution or `unreachable!` solution should produce similar benchmark result so it's really up to you.